Prove $ \overline{\text{span}\{e^{iat}\}} \cap C_0(\mathbb{R}) = \{0\} $
Let $ \overline{\text{span}\{e^{iat}\}} $ be the closure of set of complex exponential functions in the space of bounded continuous functions $ C(\mathbb{R}) $, with the sup norm. Denote $ C_0(\mathbb{R}) $ as the closed subspace of $ C(\mathbb{R}) $ consisting of functions that tend to $0$ at infinity.
I am curious about the structure of $ \overline{\text{span}\{e^{iat}\}} $. I know that it is contained in the closed subspace of uniformly continuous functions on $ C(\mathbb{R}) $ and is strictly contained in $ C(\mathbb{R}) $. I believe it is also strictly contained in the closed subspace of uniformly continuous functions. In particular, I conjecture that $ \overline{\text{span}\{e^{iat}\}} \cap C_0(\mathbb{R}) = \{0\} $. At least, if this conclusion is not correct, then it should be true that $ C_0(\mathbb{R}) $ is not contained in $ \overline{\text{span}\{e^{iat}\}} $.
While I intuitively feel this is correct, I am unsure how to prove it. I suspect that the proof will be quite interesting. Any insights or directions for a rigorous proof would be greatly appreciated!

@Balajisb No, actually the norm in my question is the sup norm. I have updated the question and specified the norm explicitly.

The answer is negative as $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$ belongs to the closure of the span. You can use the fact that $\mathcal{F}(f)=f.$ The left hand side belongs to the closure of the span.
